# Sitecore MVC Custom Link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc

I am trying to create a custom link from sitecore into my view

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("CTA display", Model.Item, new { text = "<span>" +  + "</span>"})
```

I am not 100% sure what the correct way to do this is, but I want to wrap the text from the link into a  for styling. I've tried to put the `Model.Rendering.Item.Fields["CTA display"]` into there with `.Text` and it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd start by creating a SitecoreHelper extension method that allows you to modify the inner html of the element you're rendering:

```
public static HtmlString Field(this SitecoreHelper helper, string fieldName, Item item, object parameters, string innerHtml)
{
    if (helper == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("helper");
    }
    if (innerHtml.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        return helper.Field(fieldName, item, parameters);
    }
    return new HtmlString(helper.BeginField(fieldName, item, parameters).ToString() + innerHtml + helper.EndField().ToString());
}
```

This will allow you to pass an optional `innerHtml` string that will be inserted between opening and closing tags of your element (in this case, an `<a>` tag).

From here, pass your html string containing your CTA label to the above method, or modify the method to output the field's Text value wrapped in a `<span>`.

Comment: Is there any way to append the <span> </span> before anchor text?.

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution posted above by computerjules which worked a treat.  You can then called the extended method like follows

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Link",  Html.Sitecore().CurrentItem, new {Class = "some-class"}, "<span class='some-other-class'></span>")
```

and the span is rendered within the anchor tabs